# Locale in Angular for currency use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, locale

I am pretty new to Angular (1.6.4) and basically I need to change the currency  symbols to all the values displayed in my page by setting up `$locale` to this Angular app.

Currently I have something like this:

```
{{myCtrl.getPrice() | currency : myCtrl.user.currency.symbol}}  //returns $10
```

I want to replace that line with this one:

```
{{myCtrl.getPrice() | currency}}
```

In order to use the currency set by `$locale`, but my question is how to set `$locale` ? The documentation online is very skinny on this issue.

I am grateful for any tip because I am pretty stuck right now, thanks !

Comment: are you using angular or angularjs? have you tried setting locale in the app.modules.ts file?

Comment: Angular 1.6.4 version. I have an app.module.js file but I don't know how to set it.

Comment: in which case, its angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to change `NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM` constant of `$locale` service (remember to inject it in controller):

```javascript
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$locale', function ($locale) {
  // this.user should come from somewhere ...

  $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = this.user.currency.symbol
}])
```

If you need to set currency symbol for entire application, it makes sense to change `CURRENCY_SYM` in run block of the app.

Comment: It worked man ! Thank you so much. Basically I did what you said, received this value in the constructor and changed $locale inside the constructor of my class and the change is visible along the project. Thanks !

Comment: Cool glad it works, I was just writing about that you need to access injected service in controller, but you figured it out yourself :)

Comment: There is an issue although regarding the position of the symbol, meaning that it should look like this $10 or like this 10 € in case for €. But I get €10 / $10 in both cases. How to make it know where the should be the position ? Ps. I can have many languages. Shouldn't we also set something like 'fr_FR' for example ?

Comment: If you have multiple languages, then you should better use proper localization files. If you load corresponding file (check https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n) based on the language, then all your local specific features will be automatically covered. You would not to worry about symbol position and setting CURRENCY_SYM constant.

Comment: So how to invoke i18n, what operation should I do instead of $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM =  ?

Comment: You need to include localization file for necessary language: `<script src="node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>`. Check this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: And in case I have onle GBP and EURO do I need to user i18n ?

Comment: You said you have multiple languages? In any case it's up to you, you can implement everything without extra files if you only need it for two languages and you only need currency symbol (check `negPre: "-", negSuf: " ¤", posPre: "", posSuf: " ¤"` under `NUMBER_FORMATS.PATTERNS[1]` for euro sign).